# NicEdit doesn't save textarea when form submitted through javascript href

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit, nicedit

The Problem that NicEdit won't save a textareas content when the form is submitted by a javascript was discussed on http://www.netshinesoftware.com/index.php?cID=128&bID=102 but the solution of

`for(var i=0;i<editor1.nicInstances.length;i++){editor1.nicInstances[i].saveContent();}`

OR

`editor1.addEvent('blur', function() {
this.nicInstances[0].saveContent();
});`

Won't work when the editors are created by this:

`bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });`

Any ideas why? All solutions (jquery etc. are welcome)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, but this work for me.

```
function submitForm()
{
    var data = new Object();
    var nicE = new nicEditors.findEditor('text');
    var html = nicE.getContent().replace(/\"/ig,'&quot;');

    data["projectid"] = $('select#projects option:selected').val();
    data["type"] = $('select#type option:selected').val();
    data["taskid"] = $('select#taskid option:selected').val();
    data["tasktype"] = $('select#tasktype option:selected').val();
    data["title"] = $('input#title').val().replace(/\"/ig,'&quot;');
    data["text"] = html; 

    xajax_task_action('save_importtask',data);
}
```

If you have more than one nicEdit Instance than use the iteration and save the content in an array.
I hope it will help you to figure out a solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It keeps showing "TypeError: nicE.getContent is not a function", just can't figure out why. Oh maybe I should mention I'm calling this code on every click at the moment to test....not only on submit.

Comment: Ok it's only a workaround but this helped me to save the content of my textarea (which has neither id or class and I usually only have one textarea per page). I'm setting a the POST-Var every time the user clicks somewhere...not great but works for me here.

`$(document).click(function() {
if($('#contentRight').find('.nicEdit-main').text()){
var myText = $('#contentRight').find('.nicEdit-main').text();
var input = $("<input>")
.attr("type", "hidden")
.attr("name", "text").val(myText);
      $('#formular').append($(input));
  
}
});`